# Please How I can solve this probleme?

Tags: android, bundle, proguard, android-app-bundle, android-r8

**When I publish the new version (Release) of my app in my console account, he show me this message**

There are no unclogging files associated with this App Bundle. If you are using obfuscated code (R8/ProGuard), importing an unclogging file will simplify the analysis and debugging of crashes and ANRs. You can reduce the size of the app with R8/ProGuard.

Comment: It's not a problem.  Its a warning.  Your app is obfuscated.  If you don't upload the unobfuscation file, it won't be able to unobfuscate your stack traces for you, you'd need to do it yourself.  But you don't have to if you don't want to.

Comment: thx a lot.Please How i can do it ?